# Pygame closes despite while loop

Tags: python, pygame

When I run pygame the window opens for a fraction of a second and then immediately closes. I followed multiple tutorials and followed them word for word but the problem still continues.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

(width, height) = (300, 300)
window = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

run = True
while run:
    window.fill(255,255,200)
    
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False



pygame.quit()
```

The window doesn't fill either so it feels like the while loop never runs in the first place.

Comment: Is this code exactly as the code you're running? `window.fill(255,255,200)` is not correct as it takes the color as a single argument (a tuple) not as 3 separate arguments. What errors do you get? Please post the full stack trace (full error message) into the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The argument of [`fill`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill) needs to be a tuple with 3 components, instead of 3 separate arguments:

<s>`window.fill(255,255,200)`</s>

```py
window.fill( (255, 255, 200) )
```

Comment: That fixed it, but now the display is black and not off-white like I want.

Comment: @hazm4t Add  [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) at the end of the application loop.